# Some one-time only badges have been awarded multiple times

Tags: bug, badges

To answer a Meta Stack Overflow question, I compiled a list of badges which have been awarded multiple times to a single user with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/518699/655770/). To my surprise, it includes some well-known 'one-off' badges like [Autobiographer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer).

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/518700) is a query which shows all 64 instances I could find on Stack Overflow. While I could imagine that this is a leftover from an account merge, in the first [two](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/222/altruist?userid=409473) [instances](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol?userid=2679536) I checked it looks more like a buggy script run. It also doesn't explain why [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/221/benefactor?userid=10755) is the highest [Benefactor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/221/benefactor) of the site.

The problem occurs for other sites like [Superuser](https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/518700) as well, though less often.

Comment: Well, he awarded the bounties together, with less than a minute difference. When the script ran, it saw two awarded bounties, probably the bug is there. (Should only take one.)

Comment: Also a long(?) outstanding case of a user being awarded three Fanatic badges (in 5 min intervals) on [math.se]: [Awarded extra 'fanatic' badges](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/22195).