# Strange behavior of [caucus] badge

Tags: bug, badges, election

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/80/caucus

> Visit an election **during any phase of an active election** and have enough reputation to cast a vote. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

But this member received badge for previous elections too. Even though obviously they weren't active at that time.

> [image]

Probably, if the member open old election page while new one is active, he receives the badge. Not sure if it is an intended behavior.

Comment: Related: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9611/15479.

Comment: This could be the result of an account merge; ru.SO mods should be able to check that.

Comment: @Glorfindel I don't see any account merges in the history.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot you are a moderator, and your diamond isn't showing here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsLbV.png

Comment: @Glorfindel oh, you were right. Mod merged accounts. So, probably, merged account had this badges. Right?

Comment: Yes. I now realize that [one of the first bugs I reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281744/295232) might have the same root cause.

Comment: @Glorfindel you can write it as answer, so I'll be able to accept it )

Comment: Maybe I'll do, but we can also wait for a Stack Exchange developer to confirm it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this has sat for more than a year without an answer I'll answer this question.

Erroneous appearing badges can result from: Merges, Script faults (counting twice when a change is made in the same minute), all cases not being handled, etc.

Some examples:

- MSE - [Some one-time only badges have been awarded multiple times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281744/some-one-time-only-badges-have-been-awarded-multiple-times)

  Multiple 'one-off' badges awarded to one user
- MSE - [Analytical badge awarded recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188030/282094)

  Merged-to account gets all the badges (usually, see below)
- MSO - [Why are people getting Documentation Pioneer badge in December 2016?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/340115/3648282)

  Badge awarded after it was discontinued
- MSE - [account merge gone bad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122458/account-merge-gone-bad)

  Flags (and the corresponding badges) are lost from the merged account

In the case of your question, it [was noticed that the badges are the result of a merger](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335091/strange-behavior-of-caucus-badge#comment1099998_335091).